# Remove row when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I am trying to do this using HtmlService in a Google App Script.   I have researched it and I cannot figure out why the below doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/pfue7b71/

Script

```
function removeRow() {
  //  alert("run");
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
};
```

Html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow()" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow()" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow()" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow()" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the context of the function. The immediate code that runs on the `onClick` attribute, works using the object context, so it has the right reference to `this` as the current object, but the call to `removeRow` is made on Window context, so the reference to `this` is Window, and not the object. You could solve that with your current code doing this:

```
function removeRow(object){
    $(object).closest('tr').remove();
};
```

And changing the calls to:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/pfue7b71/2/

Also, for future reference, you should try using `console.log` instead of `alert`, and use it to log important things like, for example, `$(this)`

Comment: Where can I see the console.log, if I am using htmlService in App Script?  I know how to do it in the .gs file but not in the html file.

Comment: Just answered my own question.  I have to go to the browser and open the Developer Tools Console.

Comment: Hopefully you found out alone, because I don't even know what's an htmlService in App Script xD

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `this` is referencing the DOM element, not the function.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" onClick="removeRow(this)" value="X"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You also need to rename the function to `removeRow`, as you're calling it in the HTML (was incorrect in fiddle).

```
function removeRow(e) {
    $(e).closest('tr').remove();
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pfue7b71/3/